# Is it possible to solve $\cos(x) + 2e^{x} = 0$ analytically?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, closed-form

My Calculus textbook uses $f(x) = \sin(x) + e^{2x}$ as an example of a function with infinitely many local extrema.  That much is clear, because $\cos(x) + 2e^{x} =0 $ has infinitely many solutions for $x<0$.  I'm curious if there is a way to solve 
\begin{equation}
\cos(x) + 2e^{x} =0
\end{equation}
exactly.  The only thought I've had so far is to write this as
\begin{equation}
e^{ix} + e^{-ix} + 4e^{x} = 0
\end{equation}
and go from there, but I haven't had much luck.

Comment: I think you can get asymptotics in the $x\to -\infty$ limit.  For example, we can put $x=-(n+1/2)\pi +y$, where $y$ is small, which changes the equation to something like $(-1)^k\sin(y)+2e^{-(n+1/2)\pi}e^y=0$.  Taylor expanding about $y=0$ gives $(-1)^k y\approx - 2e^{-(n+1/2)\pi}+O(e^{-2n})$.

Comment: @user254433 Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but $\cos(x) + 2e^{x} \sim \cos(x)$ as $x\to -\infty$, but somehow that's unsatisfying.

Comment: You're right, the roots will approximate those of $\cos(x)$.  What I outlined was how to slightly improve that approximation.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x_n)=\cos(x_n)+2e^{x_n}$$
$$f'(x_n)=2e^{x_n}-\sin(x_n)$$
now use the iterative formula:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{2e^{x_n}+\cos(x_n)}{2e^{x_n}-\sin(x_n)}$$
this is probably the easiest numerical way to solve it

Edit:

In terms of using:
$$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}+4e^x=0$$
we can express this as:
$$\left(e^x\right)^{i}+\left(e^x\right)^{-i}+4e^x=0$$
so if we let $u=e^x$ we get:
$$u^i+u^{-i}+4u=0$$
which I do not think can be solved

Comment: You can choose the starting values $x_0= -(2k+1)\tfrac{\pi}{2},k=0,1,2\dots$ for the iterations. E.g. for $k=0$ you get the solution $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}-0.3099$ or for $k=2$ the value is $x=-\frac{5\pi}{2}-0.000776$. For larger $k$ the solutions will be very close to $-(2k+1)\tfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: ah that looks good yeah

Answer (score 1):

Here's the closest I can think of to a solution without a computer.  Note that on $[0,\infty)$, $e^x$ outgrows $\cos x$ quickly. It is easy to verify, thus that $2e^x+\cos x$ is always greater than $0$ in this range (just check a few derivatives). If $x$ is negative with a large magnitude, then $e^{x}$ is tiny, so the solution to your equation is akin to the solutions of $\cos x=0$, which as you know are given by $x=\pi(n+1/2)$ for integral $n$. Meanwhile, if $x$ is negative but with a small magnitude, perhaps you can try linear approximations for the function near the roots of $\cos x$, and see how much that is expected to change due to the added part of $e^x$.